# How to find the dates of a calendar week?

Tags: c#, .net

How to get the date of a specific week in a specific year?

For example: I have the data week 30, year 2009 - how I can get the date of the week?

Language is C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample for code that does it:

```
int workWeek = 30;
int year = 2009;

var firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
var firstDayOfWorkWeek = firstDayOfYear.AddDays((workWeek - 1) * 7);
```

This code assumes that the work week start on the day of the 1/1/YYYY (meaning week can start from Wednesday for example).

If you want to normalize it to Sunday:

```
firstDayOfWorkWeek = 
               firstDayOfWorkWeek.AddDays(-(int) firstDayOfWorkWeek.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: It don't work, I tried both. I tried with week 30, year 09. In my calender it's Monday. 20.07.2009. But in your algorithm its the 29.07.2009

Comment: You're right, it should be '(workWeek - 1) * 7' instead of 'workWeek * 7 - 1'